# What's the best way of web api authentication to Microsoft Graph to access emails in the service account mailbox?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to figure out which way would be better for my application. I need to perform an automatic email import triggered from ASP.NET Core Web API using Microsoft Graph mailbox access. According to the documentation, there are two options to go for:

1. Get access on behalf of the user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0)
2. Get access without the user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0)

As the import is automatically triggered by Azure Function timer I do not want to open a popup for the user credentials. So I considered to go with the second option and create a service user to do this, but then I saw a point about Admin consent in the documentation and I got a bit confused. Does this mean that if nobody is going to accept the app rights to access emails it will not be able to do so? What would be easier/preferred way to implement this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--Does this mean that if nobody is going to accept the app rights to access emails it will not be able to do so?

no, that means after admin consent the api permission, then you can access any users'  emails in your tenant.

--What would be easier/preferred way to implement this kind of functionality?

as you said that you are using Azure timer function to to auto import the mails, so you shouldn't get access to graph api on behalf of a user, you have to access the api on behalf the application.

But you have to check if the graph api you want to call support being accessed on behalf of the application. Let's see [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). You may notice that it supports `Application` api permission.

[image]

Then pls note that you have to using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to generate access token to call the graph api, you can't use other flows. Here's sample code for using client credential flow with graph SDK to call graph api.

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_appid";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var inboxMessages = await graphClient.Users["user_id"]
                        .MailFolders["inbox"]
                        .Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: And if access to all users email is too much, you can create an application policy restricting access for that application to a single mailbox